# MongoDB and Mock testing: change argument for MongoTemplate.save(obj)

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I use **MongoDB 3.2.1** + **SpringDataMongoDB 1.8.2.RELEASE** and **Mockito 2.0.2-beta**.

I have User class:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    @Id
    private String id;
    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    private String name;
    private String password;
    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    private String email;

    public User() { }

    public User(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(String name, String password, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

And DAO layer for it (part of them):

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private Logger LOGGER;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "mongoTemplate")
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public User create(User user) {
        LOGGER.debug("UserDaoImpl.create: "+user);
        mongoTemplate.insert(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Now I want mock `mongoTemplate` like this:

```
@Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = Mockito.mock(MongoTemplate.class);
    List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    allUsers.add(new User("2323", "22", "1@1.1"));
    allUsers.add(new User("2323derfvb", "22234", "2@2.2"));
    Mockito.when(mongoTemplate.findAll(User.class)).thenReturn(allUsers);

    // **Don't work: it doesn't fill ID field for user**
    Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        ((User) args[0]).setId("2342");
        return null;
    }).when(mongoTemplate).insert(User.class);

    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

Unfortunately I have a problem. `mongoTemplate` fill the `id` field when it called method `mongoTemplate.insert(user)` and I can return `id` field as answer from DAO. But **Mockito** can't change the arguments if mocked method return `void`. I can only do:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(mongoTemplate).insert(User.class);
```

bit in this case I can't change the `user` argument. Chain like

```
Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
    ((User) args[0]).setId("2342");
    return null;
}).doNothing().when(mongoTemplate).insert(User.class);
```

doesn't help too.

Can anyone say me how I can change input parameter in this case?

Comment: This question is hard to understand. I don't have it clear where is it that you want to update a method's argument, or what method exactly are you trying to mock and under what circumstance. Try something like: 
-- I want to mock method X, with [p,q,r] params. 
-- I want to update those params when the method execute using Mockito.doAnswer. 
-- When I call method X under circumstance A it behaves like ..., but when I try it under circumstance B it behaves like ... 
I think this is what you are trying to say, but I'm not quite sure.